# How to count empty lines in python

Tags: python, if-statement, is-empty

I am reading a file containing empty lines and words, such as "CAR" and "V3HICL3", for example. I want to write only legitimate words into another file. To do that I want to remove empty lines and words with errors( containing numerals here). I also want to count how many lines were read, removed and accepted. I am having issues capturing the empty lines. In my list, I have: car, v3hicl3, "empty". I fail to count the empty lines. Tried the isspace and line == "\n". Doesn't seem to work. How would I count that last empty line of the document?

```
import sys
def read():
    file_name = input("Name of the file to be read: ")
    try:
        file = open(file_name, 'r')
        lst = []
        line_num = 0
        accept_line = 0
        reject_line = 0
        empty_line = 0
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip() 
            if (len(line.strip()) == 0):
                line_num += 1
            if (line == "\n"):
                line_num += 1
            if (len(line) != 0):
                line_num += 1
            if (line.isalpha()):
                accept_line += 1
                lst.append(line)
            else:
                reject_line += 1
    print("Read", line_num, "lines")
    print("Rejected", reject_lines, "lines")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("open", file_name, "failure.")
        sys.exit(0)
    file.close()
    return lst, accept_line
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: `if (line == "\n"):` will never be true, because `line.strip()` removes newlines.

Comment: You don't need to call `strip()` again in `len(line.strip())`. You already stripped it.

Comment: You're incrementing `line_num` when the length is 0 and when the length is not 0. Did you mean to increment `empty_line` instead of `line_num`?

Comment: @Barmar, right, my bad. That was careless. I copied the code you provided below, in the answers section, there are 0 empty lines. I was using a test file with just 2 words and an empty line at the end. It should be detected, but it is not. I guess it should be 3 lines read, 1 accepted, 1 rejected, 1 empty.

Comment: I didn't think you wanted to count the empty lines in `line_num`. If you want to count all lines, do that outside any of the `if` blocks.

Comment: @Barmar, got it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing `line_num` for both empty and non-empty lines. You should be incrementing `empty_lines` when `len(line) == 0`.

Since `line_num` should count all lines, increment that outside any of the conditionals.

```
import sys

def read():
    file_name = input("Name of the file to be read: ")
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
            lst = []
            line_num = 0
            accept_line = 0
            reject_line = 0
            empty_line = 0
            for line in file:
                line_num += 1
                line = line.strip() 
                if (len(line) == 0):
                    empty_line += 1
                elif (line.isalpha()):
                    accept_line += 1
                    lst.append(line)
                else:
                    reject_line += 1

        print("Read", line_num, "lines")
        print("Rejected", reject_lines, "lines")
        print("Empty", empty_line, "lines")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("open", file_name, "failure.")
        sys.exit(0)
    return lst, accept_line
```

Answer (score 0):

When `len(line.strip()) == 0` you have to increment `empty_line` also

**You may use this**

```
 import sys
    def read():
        file_name = input("Name of the file to be read: ")
        try:
            file = open(file_name, 'r')
            lst = []
            line_num = 0
            accept_line = 0
            reject_line = 0
            empty_line = 0
            for line in file:
                line = line.strip() 
                if (len(line.strip()) == 0):
                    line_num += 1
                    empty_line += 1
                if (line == "\n"):
                    line_num += 1
                if (len(line) != 0):
                    line_num += 1
                if (line.isalpha()):
                    accept_line += 1
                    lst.append(line)
                else:
                    reject_line += 1
            print("Read {} lines".format(line_num))
            print("Rejected {} lines".format(reject_line))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("open", file_name, "failure.")
            sys.exit(0)
        file.close()
        return lst, accept_line
```